# How to get evicted value from org.apache.cayenne.util.concurrentlinkedhashmap?

Tags: java, spring, caching, concurrenthashmap, linkedhashmap

I am using `org.apache.cayenne.util.concurrentlinkedhashmap` and setting cache capacity by using `maximumWeightedCpacity(3000)` method once cache reached to its threshold limit it starts evicting the old entries. I need that entries which is getting evicted. How Can I get those entries using listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an embedded copy of the [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap) library. The [tutorial](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap/wiki/ExampleUsage#listening-to-evictions) provides an example using an `EvictionListener` and can be written as,

```java
ConcurrentMap<K, V> cache = new ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.Builder<K, V>()
    .maximumWeightedCapacity(3_000)
    .listener((key, value) ->
        System.out.printf("Evicted key=%s, value=%s%n", key, value))
    .build();
```

While this library is small and nibble, it was written in the Java 5 timeframe. It is still excellent for embedded cases to minimize the jar size, but general purpose usages should prefer [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) instead. That library provides a richer feature set and additional performance improvements.

```java
Cache<K, V> graphs = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .maximumSize(3_000)
    .removalListener((K key, V value, RemovalCause cause) ->
        System.out.printf("%s: key=%s, value=%s%n", cause, key, value))
    .build();
```

Comment: the first one  ConcurrentLinkedHashMap of cayenne does not have public listener so I am not able to use it.
I used the second one 'Caffeine' and it worked for me. 
Thanks..! great help.